# ejs template expression in ejs template expression (not include)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My `node` version is v10.2.1, `express` version is 4.16.0, `ejs` version is 2.5.7.

I want to be able to change the name of the layout at a later time.

So I routing like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'my homepage' , layout: 'basic'});
});
```

and `index.ejs`

And I wrote an include in the index like this:

```
<% include ./layouts/basic/header.ejs %>
```

Now, I want to change `basic` to `<%= layout %>` but,

```
<% include ./layouts/<%= layout>/header.ejs %>
```

causes:

```
Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
```

And,

```
<% include ./layouts/%><%= layout %><%/header.ejs %>
```

causes:

```
 Could not find the include file "./layouts/"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is layouts in this case, is it variable or something else?

Comment: The user can be select layout what they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering that you required two header views

- horizontal header
- vertical header

So inside views directory I have created the respective directories.
**index.ejs**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
      </head>
      <body>
        <%if(layouts=='horizontal'){%>
            <%include ./horizontal/header%>
        <%}%>
        <%if(layouts=='vertical'){%>
            <%include ./vertical/header%>
        <%}%>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here I have passed `layouts` variable from the routes. Hope it helps you to resolve the issue.